# Работа со строкой в ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Я начинающий программист в ассемблер и сейчас выполняю задания по работам со строками и столкнулся с проблемой написания кода в котором будет следующий функционал:
Вводится строка к примеру abcdef\0
И нужно убрать все символы соответствующие ASCii % 4 == 0
Проблема в 2 вещах:
1. Символ \0 подходит под условие, но он должен остаться
2. Это то что сделать надо на битовых операциях, т.е. без деления

Может кто подсказать как это можно сделать или показать код как это сделать?

Comment: А могу попросить код, если не затруднит?

Answer (score 0):

Схематично

```
    mov si,source
    mov di,destination
    cld
repeat:
    lodsb
    stosb
    or al,al
    jz done
    and al,4
    jnz repeat
    dec di
    jmp repeat
done:
```

PS. Возможно, синтаксис требует загрузки адресов буферов в одной из форм:

```
mov si, offset source
lea si, source
```

Это уже поправьте самостоятельно.

Comment: А как можно написать Знаяение rsi = значение rdi

Comment: Вы что, хотите in-place всё это проделать? да ради бога... это показанному коду по барабану... тогда вторая строка будет `mov di,si`...